# Find the closest div in the appended element [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am trying to display some data in the appended div by clicking anchor which has been appended too.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br><append></append><br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 15">add</button>
</div>

</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('append').append('<a href="#">click me</a><div class="show-data"></div><br>');
});

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).closest('.show-data').html('hello');
})
```

You can try it from here https://jsfiddle.net/vkuzdgsL/

So my goal is to display the **hello** word within the `<div class="show-data"></div>` but using the `$(this).closest('.show-data')` function doesn't seem to work. If I replace the `.show-data` with `div`, it will detect the parent div instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) work up the tree like looking for parents, so it doesn't work in your case as the element is next to it not in ancestors tree.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) as name suggests looks for next element.

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).next('.show-data').html('hello');
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6dwrtgzx/)

Comment: If `next()` is for sibling, so what function that we use for cousin?